# How to avoid jenkins notifications being caught in gmail spam filters

Tags: jenkins, gmail

- I am using a Jenkins build server.
- I am sending an unstable build notification to myself only.
- The email I use is real and is in my domain
- I can access the domain admin console (if it might help)

The emails I sent are currently caught by the spam filter from the second I started sending them.

What are the methods I can use (within these constraints) to make sure my mails pass the spam filter?

Edit: Just to be clear, I know that I can click the "Not Spam" link and solve the problem for myself, but then when I connect it to more developers it might be considered spam again...

Comment: Can you post the message header? (In Gmail, "Show Original"). Or, just look in the header and look for "SPF" related lines. Is your domain using an SPF record, and is your Jenkins server IP address or DNS name listed as a valid SPF sender?

Comment: Received-SPF: neutral

Comment: Hmm, I doubt neutral would trigger it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is some useful information I found to solve the problem.

- The first relevant place is in the admin dashboard -> Services -> Gmail -> General Settings -> Spam.
- First of all you can set the "Bypass spam filters for messages received from internal senders." - *Didn't help*
- Then below that you can add a new group of addresses or domains that pass the spam filter - I created a new group and added the email I needed. There is a check-box below the address list "Do not require sender authentication (not recommended)." If I mark this unrecommended box - *it works*.

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins sending email report to gmail

turn on gmail access to less secured apps here [gmail app access change](https://www.google.com/settings/u/1/security/lesssecureapps)

Jenkins configuration, under email notification settings set

```
E-mail Notification
SMTP server     - smtp.gmail.com
Default user e-mail suffix  -   gmail.com
User Name       - your gmail account username
Password        - your gmail account password
Use SSL         - yes
SMTP Port       - 465
Reply-To Address    - reply email   
Charset     -UTF-8
```